# Specified Sorting [except ACS & DESC diesction] on Extjs Pivot Grid leftAxis items

Tags: extjs, grid, pivot

How Can I Sort the Left Axis Items of Extjs Pivot Grid by a specific order.For Example If I wana  Show left Axis in this Sort --> First E then C Then after M.

Comment: We're going to need to see some sample code if we're going to try and help.

Comment: Please provide addition information or share the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

See the **Ext.Store.filter()** method in the [Ext 3.3 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/air/). You can pass in an array of filters to make your grid filter by those properties in that specific order.